# NuGet Package Restore: Visual Studio Online & POSTSHARP

Tags: postsharp, azure-devops, nuget-package-restore

I installed POSTSHARP as a nuget package and I want Visual Studio Online to automatically restore it.

POSTSHARP must be restored before build though.

I am trying to follow this with no success: [link](http://doc.postsharp.net/##nuget-restore)

How can I run scripts / commands in Visual Studio Online BEFORE build?

Answer (score 2):

There are instructions on nuget.org on how to set up a package restore with TFS, including Visual Studio Online: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore-with-team-build

It mentions that the default Build Process Templates for VSO already implements NuGet Package Restore workflow. So, supposedly, you need to do additional setup only when you customize the templates.

The proposed approach is to create a simple MSBuild project file that will be used to build the solution. You can include all the required targets there (e.g. Build, Rebuild, Clean) that will just invoke MSBuild on your solution file with specifying the corresponding target.

Additionally create a target for package restore - it will invoke `NuGet.exe restore MySolution.sln` command. The common build targets will depend on this one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0"
         DefaultTargets="Build" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutDir>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)bin</OutDir>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <ProjectProperties>
        OutDir=$(OutDir);
        Configuration=$(Configuration);
    </ProjectProperties>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Solution Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)src\*.sln" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="RestorePackages">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)tools\NuGet\NuGet.exe&quot; restore &quot;%(Solution.Identity)&quot;" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="RestorePackages">
    <MSBuild Targets="Build"
             Projects="@(Solution)"
             Properties="$(ProjectProperties)" />
  </Target>

  <!-- other targets... -->

</Project>
```